# MySql Cannot Show DataTypes

Tags: mysql

I created my own database tables but I gave datatypes like 
name varchar(45)
surname varchar(45)

but when i gave for example
id int(11),

i saw them in mysql just like (11)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaMcm.jpg). Why i have this problem?

İf i write this query SHOW COLUMNS FROM enpos_gib_satis FROM enpos_gib_db;

İ saw my datatypes normally,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02i6x.jpg)
my chartset utf8 / collection utf8_bin (also i gave utf8_generel_ci).

Comment: Well, that's a problem with your frontend, not with MySQL

Comment: What I should do to fix it ? do you have any suggest? fancyPants

Comment: I don't use frontends and you haven't even mentioned, which frontend you use.

Comment: I was using mysql workbench 6.7 after that i upload mysql to 8.0 now when i run my all table script I got this error ,